# Generating Id unique in EJB session bean in a Java Web Application

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

I tried to generate and unique long id. I generate this in a service this is the service:

```
package x.y.z;

import java.util.Map; 
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import javax.ejb.Startup; 
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import  x.y.NiceObject;


@Stateless 
@Startup 
public class Transacciones {

     private  long idTransaccion = 0l;

     static Map<Long, NiceObject> mapaTransacciones = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();         

     public Transacciones() {
     }

    public long getIdTransaccion() {        
      ++idTransaccion;      
       return idTransaccion;    
     }

    public void setIdTransaccion(long idTransaccion) {
        idTransaccion = idTransaccion; 
    }

    public Map<Long, NiceObject> getMapaTransacciones() { 
        return mapaTransacciones;   
    }

    public void setMapaTransacciones(Map<Long, NiceObject> mapaTransacciones) {          
    this.mapaTransacciones = mapaTransacciones;     
    } 
}
```

And I have a managed bean from where I call this service and try to consume this id Generated. This is the method of the bean:

```
@EJB
private Transacciones transaccionService;


    public String capture() {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        try {
            long idTransaccion = 
            transaccionService.getIdTransaccion();
            method1(idTransaccion);
            service.submit(() -> {
                method2(idTransaccion);
            });
        } finally {
            if (service != null)
                service.shutdown();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The problem is that in some place in the time, it fails; because I hope to get generate Id like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6.......
```

but I get:

```
1,2,1,3,4,2,...
```

In this line:

```
long idTransaccion = transaccionService.getIdTransaccion();
```

What would be the problem. Remenber I have a Managed Bean of SessionScope from where I invoque this method in a EJB.

For any help Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the meaning of  "stateless" in a session bean (you are annotating `Transacciones` with `@Stateless`)?

Comment: Can you just save current transactionId to database and read it from disc instead of keeping it in the Transacciones instance?

Comment: Tuby thanks see my update please. Database is a solution. But I think the access to database is more slow that doing in memory... I choose this solution for that reason.

Comment: _"What would be the problem. Remenber I have a Managed Bean of SessionScope from where I invoque this method in a EJB."_. The issue has nothing to do with where you are invoking the stateless session bean. From the ejb 3 specification: A stateless session bean (1) Maintains _no state_ from one method invocation to next. (2) Has no conversational state and not dedicated to a client.

Comment: You cannot have `idTransaccion` instance variable in a stateless session bean `Transacciones`. Statelessness means - no state; that means no instance variables. You have to find some other way to create, store and retrieve unique id's. Try searching the net (Google) with a search string like "ejb generating unique ids".

Answer (score 0):

There is a pool of stateless bean. And each call is delegated to a different instance actually you call a method of proxy and it delegates your call to an instance of the pool. There is no guarantee that even two consecutive calls on a bean(injected in your bean) use the same bean. So when regenerates 1, it means that it used another bean. You could use the singleton instead of stateless.
As @prasad_3 said you must not have state in a stateless bean.

Answer (score -1):

Define  idTransaccion as static variable.

Comment: Thanks santosh. But I supposed: I don't instance an new object of the service. Why need to make static this variable in this class?

Comment: @FernandoPie . I think your session is getting lost because of that you are getting random value .

Comment: Thanks. It could be. But making static 
How could it help?